# how to display log data into colorful manner in angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, log-viewer

I am working on a feature where need to display logs data from various app into an angular app.

I have back-end services which reads logs data for selected app and send them to angular UI.

I am using a text area control to display these logs but it looks very ugly.

Is there any free angular/javascript package available for view logs data in more colorful manner?

Comment: the logs are app specific. I am not sure if such package exists. Did u try to google it ? What was the result ?

Comment: You could just add different color in css based on logs?

Comment: I did google it a lot but couldn't find anything as log data viewer. I just simply need some sort of control that can display txt log data (ex. log4net logs) into more appealing manner.

Comment: Coloring in css would be more manual approach and I'll use this as last option if there is no such package available for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use prism.js, I'm not sure if it has out of the box support for syslog kind of syntax highlighting but you can extend it for your needs. https://prismjs.com/extending.html

Comment: Thanks... I'll try this